# Description Attribute Editor Issue in Magento 2.3

Tags: product-attribute, multistore, magento2.3, editor

I am developing website with multiple stores and each store has product description in different language.

My description attribute scope is Store View. When I'm going to change description store wise and uncheck the checkbox Use Default Value, although Description Editor is remain disabled and I can't change description.

I have also checked for JS error but there is not any errors.

Comment: I have the same problem.
Have you find any solution ? Regards
Ben